# Docusign API different UI

Tags: docusignapi

We have Apttus via which we use docusign and they use the classic UI of docusign.

Now we have enabled embedded signing for certain users and when we invoke the docusign URL, the UI is of the new docusign which is not a consistent User experience.

We are using the same account so wanted to check what do we need to disable or enable to have the Classic UI for both user sets

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of the UI you are seeing.